# How to display player's score on Pygame?

Tags: python, memory

I'm a new programmer working on a memory game for my computer science summative.The game goes like this: the computer displays random boxes at random positions and then the user has to guess where the boxes are and click on it.

I'm basically done, except right now I'm trying to create 5 different levels that range in level of difficulty. eg level 1 will display 2 boxes and level 2 will display 5, etc. And then if the user gets through all levels they can play again. I know its a lot but I really want to get an A on this.

But right now I'm stuck because it doesn't really work until I try to close the window, and even then it only goes halfway. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import pygame , sys
import random
import time
size=[500,500]
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)

# Colours
LIME = (0,255,0) 
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
PINK = (255,102,178)
SALMON = (255,192,203)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
LIGHT_PINK = (255, 181, 197)
SKY_BLUE = (176, 226, 255)
screen.fill(BLACK)

# Width and Height of game box
width=50
height=50

# Margin between each cell
margin = 5

rows = 20
columns = 20


# Set title of screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Spatial Recall")

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock=pygame.time.Clock()


coord=[]

# Create a 2 dimensional array. A two dimesional
# array is simply a list of lists.
def resetGrid():
    grid = []
    for row in range(rows):
        # Add an empty array that will hold each cell
        # in this row
        grid.append([])
        for column in range(columns):
            grid[row].append(0) # Append a cell  
    return grid

def displayAllPink(pygame):
    for row in range(rows):
        for column in range(columns):
            color = LIGHT_PINK
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,[(margin+width)*column + margin,(margin+height)*row+margin,width,height])
            pygame.display.flip()      

def displayOtherColor(pygame,grid):
    coord = []
    for i in range(random.randint(2,5)):
        x = random.randint(2, rows-1)
        y = random.randint(2, columns-1)                
        color = LIME    
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,[(margin+width)*y + margin,(margin+height)*x+margin,width,height])
        coord.append((x,y))  
        grid[x][y] = 1
        pygame.display.flip() 
    time.sleep(1)
    return coord

def runGame(gameCount,coord,pygame,grid):
    pygame.event.clear()
    pygame.display.set_caption("Spatial Recall: Level "+ str(gameCount))
    pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.USEREVENT,1000)
    time = 0
    #clock.tick( 
            # -------- Main Program Loop -----------
    #Loop until the user clicks the close button.
    done = False
    while done==False:    
        event = pygame.event.wait() # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            done=True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop
            pygame.event.clear()
            print "Game ",gameCount, "ends"
        elif event.type == pygame.USEREVENT:
            time = time + 1
            pygame.display.set_caption("Spatial Recall: Level "+ str(gameCount) + " Time: "+ str(time))
            if time == 100:
                done = True
                pygame.display.set_caption("Time out, moving to next level")
                pygame.event.clear()
                return False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # User clicks the mouse. Get the position
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            # Change the x/y screen coordinates to grid coordinates
            column=pos[0] // (width+margin)
            row=pos[1] // (height+margin)
            if (row,column) in coord:
                print coord
                coord.remove((row,column))
                print coord
                color = LIME
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,[(margin+width)*column + margin,(margin+height)*row+margin,width,height])
                if coord == []:
                    done=True 
                    pygame.display.set_caption("Time out, moving to next level")
                    pygame.event.clear()
                    return True
            else:
                color = RED
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,color,[(margin+width)*column + margin,(margin+height)*row+margin,width,height])
            pygame.display.flip() 


def startTheGame(gameCount):
    grid = resetGrid()
    displayAllPink(pygame)
    coord = displayOtherColor(pygame,grid)
    displayAllPink(pygame)
    runGame(gameCount,coord,pygame,grid)

for i in range(2):
    startTheGame(i+1)
pygame.quit ()
```

Comment: I recommend reducing the amount of code here.  It's a little hard to understand your problem when you've posted the entire game.

Comment: What errors do you get, if any, when you use a debugger on the program?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the `pygame.font` module.  http://pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html

- First, load a font, either from a file or from one of the system font functions.
- Call `YourFontObject.render(your_text_string)`.  That'll return a `Surface` that contains the string rendered in the given font.  Note, you can't use newline (`\n`) characters!  You'll have to do the spacing yourself.
- Blit this `Surface` onto the screen after everything else so nothing will obscure it.

Also, you don't need the `pygame` parameter in your functions.

Hope this helps.